# How does the Select() method return anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, entity-framework-4, anonymous-types

I understand that anonymous types cannot be returned from methods. I also understand that there are workaround ways of doing this. My question is, what method do Linq providers use? For example, (cue dim understanding of how Linq providers work), the `Select()` extension method is applied to an `IQueryable`, whose expression tree is parsed by the Linq provider, turned into SQL, and the query results are parsed, loaded into a type and then.... returned.

So what technique to get `Select()` to return the type is used by e.g. Entity Framework or NHibernate?

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking here, but: 1 - Methods can return anonymous types. 2 - Select() returns IEnumerable<TResult>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses generics. Through type inference, the compiler knows the exact type of the anonymous type.
Please note that the compiler automatically generates a class for anonymous types. After that, it is just a type like any other type.

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items,
                                                     Func<TSource, TResult> converter)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
        yield return converter(item);
}
```

---

You can return an anonymous type from your methods. The problem is, that you can't do that strongly typed, because the type name of the anonymous type is not known to you - but it is to the compiler, that's why generics work with anonymous types.

The workaround you are talking about is also using generics.

Comment: Ah, I see, I totally get it. The `x => new { Blah = x.Blah }` parameter you pass to `Select()` is the converter to generate the new type. The compiler knows all about the type; it's only you as the programmer that considers the type anonymous... thanks for explaining.

Comment: So am I right in thinking a method can in fact return an anonymous type, so long as the return type is generic, and it accepts a parameter identifying the type (the `TResult` part of  `Func<TSource, TResult>` in your example?

Comment: @David: About your first comment: Exactly

Comment: @David: There are several ways a method can return an anonymous type: 1) Using generics - this requires the caller to provide the anonymous type - as in `Select` 2) Using `object` as return type 3) Using `dynamic` as return type

Answer (score 2):

I believe it uses generics, so although the return type seems "anonymous" it is known because of the data type that you are using it on.

The simple fact is, the program (once compiled) knows the exact type to return based on the type that is passed in (or operated on)

You can [read some more on generics here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), they can be very very useful when coding - as long as you know when to use them appropriately

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use generics, but I've got a lot more to learn. Muse are awesome!